# Split dictionary values into two separate values

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following dictionary which I want to split the lists into two distinct lists with different keys.

```py
{
   "industry": [
      [
         "IT Services and IT Consulting",
         "New York City, NY"
      ],
      [
         "IT Services and IT Consulting",
         "La Jolla, California"
      ],
      [
         "Software Development",
         "Atlanta, GA"
      ]
   ]
}
```

I am expecting to have as output:

```py
{
   "industry": [
      "IT Services and IT Consulting",
      "IT Services and IT Consulting",
      "Software Development"
   ],
   "country": [
      "New York City, NY",
      "La Jolla, California",
      "Atlanta, GA"
   ]
}
```

Comment: What have you already tried and where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to have a `list` of `dict`ionaries rather than a `dict`ionary of `list`s?  With `list`s you have to make sure they're ordered correctly.  For example, `d["industry"][0]` and `d["country"][0]` have to be referring to the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
d = {
    "industry": [
      [
         "IT Services and IT Consulting",
         "New York City, NY"
      ],
      [
         "IT Services and IT Consulting",
         "La Jolla, California"
      ],
      [
         "Software Development",
         "Atlanta, GA"
      ]
    ]
}

res = {
    'industry': [t[0] for t in d['industry']],
    'country': [t[1] for t in d['industry']]
}
print(res)
```

prints

```
{'industry': ['IT Services and IT Consulting',
  'IT Services and IT Consulting',
  'Software Development'],
 'country': ['New York City, NY', 'La Jolla, California', 'Atlanta, GA']}
```

Alternative solution:

```
industry, country = list(zip(*d['industry']))
res = {'industry': industry, 'country': country}
```

Explanation: Given your dictionary `d`, create a new dictionary `res` by iterating over each tuple `t = (industry, country)` in the list `d["industry"]` and using the first element `t[0] = industry` for the `"industry"` list in `res` and the second element `t[1] = country` for the `"country"` list in `res` via a list comprehension (`[_ for _ in _]`).

Comment: While it's good that you know how to solve the problem, it's expected on Stack Overflow not to give direct answers to trivial or homework questions, and especially not without any explanation. Please see [How to ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Comment: @MattDMo This does not look like a homework question to me.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to transpose the data, then to combine it to the header to form an new dictionary:

```
d = {'industry': [['IT Services and IT Consulting', 'New York City, NY'],
                  ['IT Services and IT Consulting', 'La Jolla, California'],
                  ['Software Development', 'Atlanta, GA']]
    }


out = dict(zip(['industry', 'country'], map(list, zip(*d['industry']))))
```

output:

```
{'industry': ['IT Services and IT Consulting', 
              'IT Services and IT Consulting',
              'Software Development'],
 'country': ['New York City, NY',
             'La Jolla, California',
             'Atlanta, GA']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution with `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(your_dict)
df.industry.agg(pd.Series).rename(columns={0:'industry', 1:'country'}).to_dict()
```

Answer (score 0):

Using python `defaultdict` and a **single** loop,

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = {"industry":[["IT Services and IT Consulting","New York City, NY"],["IT Services and IT Consulting","La Jolla, California"],["Software Development","Atlanta, GA"]]}
result = defaultdict(list)
for i in d["industry"]:
    result["industry"].append(i[0])
    result["country"].append(i[1])
print(dict(result))
```

**Working Code:** https://rextester.com/AGAW59163